# Orthogonal Bases and Fourier Approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-series, orthonormal

I am confused about how my professor resolved a fourier approximation. The question was:
Find the fourth-order fourier approximation of: $$f(x) = \sin (5x)$$
on the interval: $$0\le x \le 2\pi$$
He said something about the given sine function being an orthonormal basis in this situation What he specifically wrote is that:

$$\{\cos (nx), \sin (nx)\} , n \in \mathbb{Z}$$ is an othonormal basis for $$C[0,2\pi]$$

He said that since the function in question is $\sin (5x)$ then that implies that it is a higher order (5) than the order of the approximation (4) which means that the approximation of the function along the interval is $0$. I don't really understand this. Why does the function's fourier approximation go to $0$ on the interval?

Is it because the given function is a sine function and the fourier approximation is composed of summations of sine and cosine functions? Or is it because the function is of $5x$ and thus the order **n** = 4 of the approximation is less than the order of the function being approximated? $\implies$ **n** < 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x)=\sin(5 x)$ is an odd function of $x$, the Fourier series for $f(x)$ only consists of $\sin$ terms, and since the Fourier sin series for $f(x)$ on the interval $(0, 2 \pi)$ is

$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n\, \sin(n x)$$

its not too hard to see that

$$a_n=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & n=5 \\
 0 & n\ne 5 \\
\end{array}\right..$$